# How do i create a custom 404 page in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: http-status-code-404, laravel-5.7

Can anyone help me to create a custom 404 page in laravel 5.7, i am new to laravel so it'd great if you tell me the flow for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `404.blade.php` file in `errors` folder inside your `views` and make customizations that you want.

OR

You can also use `vendor:publish` command to publish all the errors blade defined in core.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

This will create an `errors` folder in your `views` directory and in it there will be all error blade files. You can customize `404.blade.php` in it.

Answer (score 1):

@Kamal's solution is good if you want to use a static 404 file. For more customization you can create a proper 404 controller.

To do so first create a controller and method for handling the 404 page (or add a method to an existing controller). Then, tell Laravel to redirect to that controller if no other route was found by adding this at the end of your `routes\web.php` file. Here's an example:

```
Route::get('404', 'PageController@render_404_page');

Route::fallback(function () {
    return redirect('404');

});
```

This gives you the freedom to add more logic to 404 pages.